# Is this the Abstract Factory pattern or something else?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, singleton, factory-pattern

I have an abstract class that's following the singleton pattern, then I have a few concrete classes that extend it:

[UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdoaA.jpg)

At startup, based on the current system, I'm setting a concrete instance as the instance of the singleton like this:

LicenseFactory.setInstance(new SystemALicenseFactory())

With that, at any point in the code, I can consume the abstract method like this:
LicenseFactory.getInstance().isUserValid()

Because my concrete classes aren't creating a product, I'm not sure whether I can call this the Abstract Factory pattern or something else. Is it common to use a pattern like this, and is there anything I should have done better?

Comment: `LicenseFactory` is a [Service Locator](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Comment: @jaco0646 thank you for the Service Locator link. I realise that I'm having the same design problem as the article suggests, and I've decided to replace this with dependency injection instead.